# How to configure Dovecot to allow alias to login

Tags: postfix, alias

I use dovecot with a Mysql for user account and aliases. The aliases
are objects of the class couriermailalias.
Some users would like to use the alias address as POP/IMAP login instead of
the 'true' account.
Is this possible?.

Comment: you need to better explain what exactly you are trying to achieve. like which service you would like the virtual user to be able to log in to?

Answer (score 4):

Postfix is a MTA (Mail Transfer Agent), it gets and dispatches mail, and hands it over to whatever mail store is in use. Any "log in" or such is handled by the system allowing access to the mail store, your POP or IMAP server (or the webmail front). You'd have t check those.